# Phone number with and without international prefix

Tags: android

Suppose I receive an SMS from a contact. If I then extract their phone number from the SMS, this phone number will also have the international prefix.
Now suppose that I want to send an SMS to this contact but I avoid writing the international prefix. Out of the box the two messages won't appear in the same thread. How can I show all the messages coming from and sent to a contact, when they differ only in the prefix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

define a constant M in which you put the minimum match length and you compare last M digits from both numbers.